# How to preserve original formatting in an epub file

Tags: microsoft-word, epub

After converting a basic doc file to an html file and thereafter converting it to an epub file, certain parts of my original format is getting disturbed. For example certain paragraphs are not coming as paragraphs where it is supposed to. Is there any way to preserve the original format of the text in the final epub file?

Comment: what tool are you using ?

Comment: At the general level the answer is “No”, because there are formatting features in Word that cannot be represented using HTML and CSS, which are what epub is based on. Moreover, epub readers support varying, relatively limited sets of HTML and CSS features. To get help with your specific problem, you need to present it much more specifically: what style is used in Word, how you convert it to HTML and then to epub, and what does the relevant resulting code look like, and how does the appearance differ from the original?